# How to %w[text] in Ruby without including \n where it line wraps

Tags: ruby, string

I want to build an array of a list of state abbreviations, and since it is long, I want to split it over several lines. Using %w or %W, however, includes the \n where the lines break.

```
STATES = %w(AL AK AZ AR CA CO CT DE FL GA HI ID IL IN IA KS KY LA ME\
  MD MA MI MN MS MO MT NE NV NH NJ NM NY NC ND OH OK OR PA RI SC SD\
  TN TX UT VT VA WA WV WI WY)
```

So `"ME"` will be `"ME\n"`, as will `"SD"` be `"SD\n"`

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just drop the slashes and there will not be any new line characters or slashes

Comment: Doh! So it does not require line continuation characters (except in cases when it does). What is the rule for requiring line continuation characters? And what is the rational for the behavior of turning the line continuation character into a new line character?

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful, but unfortunately not complete. The post says that if the end of the line is an operator or a comma the line can continue on the next one without a line continuation character. By that rule my example would need a line continuation character where you have shown it does not.

Answer (score 1):

```
irb(main):003:0* STATES = %w(AL AK AZ AR CA CO CT DE FL GA HI ID IL IN IA KS KY LA ME\
irb(main):004:0]   MD MA MI MN MS MO MT NE NV NH NJ NM NY NC ND OH OK OR PA RI SC SD\
irb(main):005:0]   TN TX UT VT VA WA WV WI WY).collect(&:chomp)
=> ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"]
```